# Hiding console window of Python GUI app with py2exe

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, py2exe

I have a Python program uses Qt (PyQt4 in fact) and when I launch it from its main.py, I get a console window and the GUI window (on Windows, of course).

Then I compile my program with py2exe and main.exe is successfully created. However, if I run main.exe (this is what users of program will do) console window of Python still appears and all my debug text is stdout-ed to that window.

I want to hide cmd line window when my application is running and I want just my GUI to be visible to the user when executed from .exe file.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yep, it is possible.

If I use

```
setup(console=['__main__.py'], options={"py2exe":{"includes":["sip"]}})
```

It creates a console app, however if I use

```
setup(windows=['__main__.py'], options={"py2exe":{"includes":["sip"]}})
```

it does not show console on .exe file. But output is dumped on main.exe.log file in the .exe folder. Be careful.

Comment: To suppress output you could redirect stdout as in http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2009/05/python-redirect-or-turn-off-stdout-and.html  or to some other logging facility.

Comment: For me, the "sip" was not recognized, but I was able to build my exe and have it work by just using "setup(windows=['fileName.py'])"

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. This is my code `setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}},
    console = ["main.pyw"],
    zipfile = None,
)`

Answer (score 6):

I doubt this has an effect on py2exe, but it's related to the question.  To run a python GUI on windows without the terminal, use pythonw.exe instead of python.exe.  This should happen automatically if you end the filename with ".pyw".

Answer (score 3):

This might not be directly related to your question but i think it is worth trying.

You easily do so Using PyInstaller by using the following code.

```
pyinstaller -w myscript.py
```

Just as simple as that and every thing is settled!

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way I found was to add `-c` when using the console to create the `.exe`.
If you type cmd into the file explorer,  then type the following: `python setup.py py2exe -c`

My setup file was set up as shown below:

```
import distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(windows=['myprogram.py'])
```