# How do I see "print"s from a python tkinter app converted to a .exe?

Tags: python, console, tkinter, py2exe

I built a tkinter app, then I converted it into a `.exe`. When I run the `.exe`, no console shows up.

But in the script, I wrote several `print "stuff"` statements, how can I display them when I run the `.exe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the `.exe` from the console.

Easiest way to start the console is Start -> Run -> `cmd.exe`

Then `cd` to the directory where the `.exe` is, and run the `.exe`.

Edit: If you used `py2exe`, you may need to pass your script to `setup()` as the `console` argument:

```
setup(console=['hello.py'])
```

This will tell it you want console output. That's from the [py2exe tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial).

Also see [Hiding console window of Python GUI app with py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275293/hiding-console-window-of-python-gui-app-with-py2exe), and do the opposite, since you *don't* want to hide the console output.

Comment: no, it doesn't work. the cmd.exe simply starts the .exe then gives out another prompt.

Comment: Did you use `py2exe`? If so, edit your post to add the contents of your `setup.py`. If not, edit it to say what you did use. I edited my answer, it may answer your question now if you did use `py2exe` but not the `console` argument.