# Py2exe compiles properly but the built application doesn't work

Tags: python, py2exe

I am using Python 2.7 to build my application. Within it, I used few packages which are `numpy`, `scipy`, `csv`, `sys`, `xlwt`, `time`, `wxpython` and `operator`.

All the above packages are in 64-bit, and I am using python 2.7(64-bit version) in Aptana Studio 3(64-bit version) in Windows 7 Professional (64-bit version).

At last, I'd like to compile my project to an application using following code, the file name is `py2exeTest.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import numpy                  # numpy is imported to deal with missing .dll file

import py2exe

setup(console=["Graphical_Interface.py"])
```

Then in `cmd`, I switched to the directory of the project and used following line to compile it:

```
python py2exeTest.py py2exe
```

Everything goes well, it generates an application under `dist` directory, and the application name is `Graphical_Interface.exe`.

I double clicked it, but there is a cmd window appears, and a python output windows flashes, then both of them disappeared. I tried to run the application as an administrator, the same outcome I've had.

May I know how to work this out?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I've managed to catch the error information that flashes on the screen. The error info I had is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Graphical_Interface.py", line 397, in <module>
  File "Graphical_Interface.py", line 136, in __init__
  File "wx\_core.pyc", line 3369, in ConvertToBitmap
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "image.Ok()" failed at ..\..\src\msw\bitmap.cpp(802) in wxBitmap::CreateFromImage(): invalid image
```

I used one PNG image in the project, the code is like follows:

```
self.workflow = wx.Image("Work Flow.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel_settings, -1, self.workflow, (330,270), (self.workflow.GetWidth(), self.workflow.GetHeight()))
```

I tried to comment the above chunk out from the project, and the application works properly. However, I need the image to show up in the application.

May I know how to deal with it?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hiding console window of Python GUI app with py2exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275293/hiding-console-window-of-python-gui-app-with-py2exe)

Answer (score 2):

- [Hiding console window of Python GUI app with py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275293/hiding-console-window-of-python-gui-app-with-py2exe)

When compiling graphical applications you can not create them as a console application because reasons (honestly can't explain the specifics out of my head), but try this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import numpy
import py2exe
import wxpython
setup(window=['Graphical_Interface.py'],
      options={"py2exe" { 'boundle_files' : 1}})
```

Also consider changing to:

- http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/

It works with Python3 and supports multiple platforms.
A [cx_freeze script](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils) would look something like:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

includefiles = ['/folder/image.png']

setup(  name = "GUIprog",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options, 'include_files' : includefiles},
        executables = [Executable("Graphical_Interface.py", base=base)])
```

Answer (score 0):

No worries, I've got the solution.

It turns out that the image is in the project folder rather than in the `dist` folder. So I have two solutions:

1. Copy the image into `dist` folder
2. Include the full path of the image in the code.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There's a solution for that as well in cx_freeze (and py2exe). Simply add `include_files` to your options with relative paths and that path will be included in the build as well :)