# Command Prompt showing for Python Executable (python 3.4)

Tags: python, cmd, py2exe

So I am designing an application in python 3.4, and I used the following website and py2exe to make it an executable file:
http://www.kosbie.net/cmu/fall-10/15-110/koz/notes-py2exe-tutorial.html

The executable is created, and works properly, but it also shows a command window right behind it. I would post an image but I need 10 reputation to do that (almost there!).

Basically, I don't want that command window you would be able to see in the background. I know I don't have too much detail here, but does anyone know how to help? If it helps, if I have any parts of the code that prints stuff using the 'print()' command (usually seen in the shell), it pops up in that command window behind my application.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: The answer proposed here should work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3275327/3646530

Comment: Oh Jeez I feel dumb. @Ashwin you got it. I tried looking this up, but I see why I couldn't find that solution. Thanks for your time.

Comment: np :) I had the same issue, so knew where to find it

Comment: When you get enough reputation, just remember to upvote that answer