# How do I stop the command prompt from appearing when I run my Python executable?

Tags: python, user-interface, command-prompt, py2exe

I compiled a Python GUI program using py2exe, and it works, but when I run it the command prompt appears in addition to my program window. I have read that I should change the python.exe file to the pythonw.exe file, but there isn't even a Python.exe file in the dist folder to begin with. Compiling a .pyw version of the file also does not fix this. How would I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275293/hiding-console-window-of-python-gui-app-with-py2exe)

You didn't post any code (which you should do), but I suspect you're using "console" instead of "windows" in setup.py.

Comment: Yes! This worked, thank you so much! Sorry about not posting code, I will make sure to do so next time, I just thought it was irrelevant and it was a file problem.