# Wrote a python script in windows 8 and used py2exe to get a single exe, when moved to windows 7 it opens cmd then closes

Tags: python, windows, py2exe

Windows 8 running in 32-bit using vs-code to write a simple python script to configure an ip address quickly through command line. Was able to successfully (after many attempts) to create a single exe with it and launch it in windows 8. Tried moving it to my other laptop running windows 7 and it would only show the command line and then close out. Not really sure what I'm missing, both machines running similar software except windows 7 is in 64-bit windows.

I'm not getting any errors and the py2exe ran without any problems. I can compile it again on my windows 7 box and try it there but would like to be able to write on one machine for both.

Any help is always appreciated.

Comment: will [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275293/hiding-console-window-of-python-gui-app-with-py2exe) help?

Comment: No I'm wanting to keep it in command line for the time being and it is already set for the command option in the setup.py py2exe file. I may try and build a gui for it later on but for now the user is just entering in a few fields in the ip address.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this the other day.

The executable created most of the time is forward compatible: 
If you create the executable in Windows XP, it will run in Vista and 7. 
However it is not backwards-compatible: if you create the executable in
Windows 7 it is not going to run on Windows XP.

From: http://www.pythoncentral.io/py2exe-python-to-exe-introduction/