# How to overcome a startup program delay?

Tags: python, windows, autostart

I've been programming with Python and have made an EXE file. 
I've added a shortcut to it in the startup folder in order to make it autostart with Windows.

The problem is that it takes some time between when the blank black console appears and the actual run of the program (i.e. it takes time until the program actually starts working).

How do I get rid of the blank black console window? I think it happens because Windows takes time to load the file's folders and libraries.

I want that the black window to be hidden at startup using `win32gui.ShowWindow(win, 0)`, but it takes too long for this to happen. It works fine when launched normally but not when run from the startup directory while Windows is starting.

Comment: How did you create the exe file?

Comment: from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['location'])


and used py2exe

Comment: Cool. Thanks ! Ps. you should be able to edit the question to add more information there.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275293/hiding-console-window-of-python-gui-app-with-py2exe

Comment: Please take care to make your title and your question match each other -- it looks like the actual question isn't about startup delay at all, but is about hiding the window.

Comment: hiding is not the problem. it hides just fine, the delay is the problem. the program makes what it should do, but in a delay of a 10 secs, in which it shows the cmd window

Comment: @BenL, it's a console window. There's no such thing as a "cmd" window. cmd.exe and python.exe, and apparently your EXE, are console applications that either inherit or cause Windows to autostart an instance of conhost.exe, which hosts the console window. Any Windows application can attach to one, and only one, console window. But "console" applications are flagged to do this automatically instead of having to manually call `AttachConsole` or `AllocConsole`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm quite a beginner so excuse me for using the wrong terms. I understand alittle better now, thanks. However, you haven't really solved the problem. there's a delay between the time the console window appears and the time the file actually starts working